# Why Bootstrap data-dismiss and modal('hide') are not working?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Firstly, I want to hide modal if there is no value in the text box. Secondly, `data-dismiss` is not working. I do not see any problem in the code. Any guesses? Please suggest me.

```
/My form
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {   
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtName)
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.hiddenNameId)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.txtName, "", new { @class = "error" })
       <button type="submit" id="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Produce Page</button>      
    } 

//My Modal

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
    ...
            <div class="modal-header">
                ...
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
  </div>

//Script

$(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        var value = $('#txtName').val(); 
        if (value) {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        }
        else {
            $("#myModal").modal('hide');
        }
    });
    });
```

Comment: did you include jquery? jQuery is required for those methods to work. (as well as the `bootstrap[.min].js`) https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always getting the model because your button is wired up to fire it using markup, using the `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes in the button markup.

Remove those and now it will not fire the modal dialog when user clicks on the button.

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" >Produce Page</button>
```

When the button is clicked, your javacsript code (the click event handler you wired up) will be executed, which will conditionally show the modal dialog based on the value of the `txtName` input.

Also, you probably do not need the code to hide it. Because use will click the button when the modal is not there (so the button on the background is clickable). In that case, all you need to do is, show the modal dialog when your if condition passes.

```
$(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $('#txtName').val();
        if (value) {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

Regarding your second problem about not closing the modal dialog, it should work as long as you have the proper markup (with the needed attributes) for the close button. (In your question, you did not post the full markup). Here is a [working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wifixuw/edit?html,output) for your reference

Comment: Thank you Shyju. But my `close` button is not working.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` is blocking my `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.txtName, "", new { @class = "error" })`

Comment: Close button should work fine. Compare with this jsbin http://jsbin.com/wifixuw/edit?html,output and see what is missing. You can always fire the jQuery validation inside javascript. Ex : `var isFormValid = $(#someFormId").valid();`

Comment: If I remove `e.preventDefault();` then my `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.txtName, "", new { @class = "error" })` works perfectly fine. But If I include that then my validation does not work. Even the link you provided is working without validation. Please guide me in my scenario. Thank you.

Comment: If you do not prevent the default behavior, your form will do a normal form submit as the clicked button is inside the form tag. As i mentioned in my previous comment, you can always fire up the validation using javascript. Read the previous comment carefully.  If needed, you can show validation messages (or anything) in the client browser because javascript code can update DOM as needed.

Comment: I want the form to do normal form submit upon `produce page` button click. The modal `data-dismiss` is not working. please provide me an idea. Should I write JavaScript to hide?

Comment: if you want to do a normal form submit on the button click, why are you having the click handler which is showing the modal dialog ?

Comment: Actually, I will pass some link  `onclick` event of  `Save changes`.  This button is not for saving the form. I will change the name afterwards. The `button` and `X` is not working at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163755/discussion-between-raj-and-shyju).